# Why are things electronegative and electropostive?

Tags: chemical-potential, chemical-compounds

Chemical reactions happen because of electron donation.  Atoms already have an equal amount of proteins and electrons, so they should cancel out and the atom should not have to steal/donate electrons.  Why do atoms have electronegativity (taking electrons) and electro positivity (donating electrons)

Comment: Individual atoms don't care. Two different atoms coming together is a different story since the energy difference in adding/subtracting an electron between them may well make it worthwhile to do so to lower overall energy.

Comment: Yes, with chemistry, as with all dynamical systems, its all about minimizing the Hamiltonian. The halogens are notably electronegative, and the total energy of the hydrogen iodide bond whereby the iodine atom steals an electron from hydrogen, has a lower energy than that of the combined system of hydrogen and iodine free radicals.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not an answer, but a few things to consider.

First, while a neutral atom has equal number of protons and electrons, the specifics of the electron orbitals are different from element to element.

Second, you should be aware that the amount of energy to remove one electron from a neutral atom also differs from element to element, a result of those electron orbitals being different. This is the first ionization energy. Not surprisingly, the second ionization energy to remove the next electron also differs from element to element.

Third, most singly-negative ions are stable (except for the noble gases). That means there is energy released by a neutral atom capturing an extra electron. While harder to measure than ionization energies, the electron affinity differs from element to element.

Now bring two atoms together to form a molecule. To form a stable molecule they will "share" one or more electrons to reduce the total energy. If the two atoms are different elements, it is clear from the above that one atom will like to grab a bit more of the shared electron, and the other will not object too strongly to giving a bit more of it away. This is all in the name of reducing the overall energy of the system.

Now, because the electron energies are tied to the elements, one can see that some elements will be more likely than others to want a bit more of the shared electron(s), and some will be happy to give away more of the shared electron(s). So, some are electropositive and some are electronegative.